# What is the standard in crypto markets, "Open Orders" or "Pending Orders"?

Tags: terminology, cryptocurrency

I am wondering what is the best way to name a section where only pending/open transaction are gonna be shown. As a crypto "broker", what will be more understandable, open or pending orders?

Comment: Have you looked into what other crypto brokers call it? What terms have you seen them use? Have you noticed if they converge on a common term, or if there's a variety of terms?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about user experience, but instead is a question about a term specific to trading cryptocurrencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Open orders** is the common term in crypto markets. 
The terms `Open Order` and `Close Order` are more common for traders.